# Tiling over rolled roof

Tags: flooring, tile, roofing

I have a walk deck made of rolled roofing material. When it rains it ponds in certain areas. Couple roofing companies looked at this, some suggested sealing the low areas with roof coating material with no warranty.

I feel like tiling could be an inexpensive solution compared to the quotes Im getting. Can i install tile over this material, do i need hardy board? Would that be an ok solution to my ponding issue? Is additional weight a problem in the future?

Answer (score 1):

"Can I install tile over this material..."

- No, not without further treatment. Composition/asphalt/rolled roofing materials are not an appropriate substrate for tile

"do i need hardy board. Would that be an ok solution to my ponding issue?"

- No, Hardiboard alone will not work and will not solve your ponding issue, the water will continue to pond *under* the cement board

"Is additional weight a problem in the future?"

- Weight *might* be a problem now and in the future, but weight as it relates to *deflection* is likely to be your biggest concern

I am afraid that you may be in for a bigger project than you envision if this is to be done properly. Rolled roofing materials are **not** an appropriate surface for walking on regularly, and ponding should not occur on an exterior deck surface designed for walking as they should always be sloped to drain or to a drain. It leads me to be suspicious of the original design and install.

To do it right would mean ensuring the deck is sloped to drain and meets minimum deflection specs (in other words, when a live load -person(s)- is/are on it, it does not flex too much). Then you will need to completely waterproof it (not just water resistant which is what rolled roofing is, *water proof*).

Down and dirty: install appropriate perimeter flashing, float concrete or "dry pack" over the existing surface to provide a slope and eliminate ponding, asphalt hot-mop (or apply some alternative high-tech waterproofer), float more concrete on that, then tile.

If it was me I would cut the deck off flush to the house and let it drop into the street, it's just a ledge for water to collect and cause damage (sorry to be pessimistic, but that's how I feel about balconies).

Comment: If i apply Redgard on hardbioard would that not stop the water from getting under and ponding? I dont think cutting the deck is an easy project, it looks like this
http://photos1.zillowstatic.com/p_f/IS1f0lcbz13ktk0000000000.jpg

Comment: @Evelyn, laying down hardibacker board and waterproofing it with Redguard, then tiling *might* work if done properly. The drain scuppers visible in the photo indicate that the deck was built with a slope, so the presence of ponding makes me worry about how sound the underlying substrate is. There are a lot of variables, including a lot of things that could go wrong later. I know this is a DIY site, but I would call a balcony/deck/waterproofing specialist.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a raised wood deck before tiling be sure the added weight can be supported. The ponding also may be because the framing members are sagging. If so than correcting the joists would be the best repair and it is within the capabilities of any knowledgeable DIY-er. If the balcony can support the weight and you'd prefer not to remove the rolled roofing than you should install a backer board. Check that the finished height of the floor will not interfere with doors or inside floor. It would be best if the exterior floor is lower than the interior floor.

Comment: it is a balcony so the weight could probably be supported, but to be sure who can give me this information?